# Download as PDF in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, pdf-generation

Stumped with printing a PDF from a Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script. Here's my script:

```
function printPdf(workbook,sheet,folderId) {// print a pdf
    var workbookId = workbook.getId();
    var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
    var name = sheet.getName() + ".pdf";

    var exportLink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + workbookId + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&size=letter&portrait=false&fitw=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&fzr=false";
    Logger.log(exportLink);

    var params = { method: "GET", headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};//,'muteHttpExceptions' : true};
    
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportLink, params).getBlob().setName(name);
    //var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportLink, params).getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(name); <--blob option 2


    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); 
    var pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);
    
    Logger.log("PDF file created: " + pdfFile.getUrl());
    return pdfFile;
}
```

This produces a document file full of HTML that is not a PDF. The exportLink in the log downloads a PDF perfectly. Blob option 2 produces a PDF, but instead of the correct content is an error message:

> Google
>
> Couldn’t sign you in
>
> The browser you’re using doesn’t support JavaScript, or has JavaScript turned off.
> To keep your Google Account secure, try signing in on a browser that has JavaScript turned on.

Seems like something is wrong with the oauth request. Appreciate any guidance.

Tried two different blob declarations. Expecting a PDF with the content of the spreadsheet.

Comment: If the answer actually worked for you (or at least contributed in finding the right solution), don't forget to upvote . By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved using the info provided in this answer.

Comment: how to do this for docs?

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your code, and it's working for me. Here are some of the changes I did:

**Export URL:**

From:

```
  var exportLink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + workbookId + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&size=letter&portrait=false&fitw=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&fzr=false";
```

To:

```
  let exportLink = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + workbook + 
  '/export?format=pdf&' +
  'size=letter&' + 
  'portrait=false&' + 
  'fitw=true&' +
  'gridlines=false&' +
  'printtitle=false&' +
  'sheetnames=false&' +
  'pagenum=false&' +
  'fzr=false&' + 
  'gid=' + sheet
```

Also, not sure how you are getting the sheet, to use `var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();`. So, I will recommend doing a logger to make sure you are getting a valid `gid`. I use `0` since is the one for `Sheet1`, and hard coded some variables.

This is the sample I used for the test:

```
let workbook = 'Google_sheet_ID';
let sheet = '0';
let folderId = 'folder_ID';

function printPDF() {
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(workbook);
  let name = file.getName() + '.pdf';

  // construct the export URL
  let url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + workbook + 
  '/export?format=pdf&' +
  'size=letter&' + 
  'portrait=false&' + 
  'fitw=true&' +
  'gridlines=false&' +
  'printtitle=false&' +
  'sheetnames=false&' +
  'pagenum=false&' +
  'fzr=false&' + 
  'gid=' + sheet

  // parameters that will be use for the blob  
  let params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  let blob_file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(name);

  //call the folder
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  //creates the PDF file in the folder
  let pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob_file);

  return pdfFile;

}
```